# How can I send a followup mail 2 days after user signup in PHP WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to send a followup mail after 2 days of signup. What should be the process of coding ? Or can it be done by any plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to run cron job. you can create a cron job from cpanel or use like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cronjob-scheduler/. this will trigger cron after 2 days. and you need to list of user email that signup last 2 days.

Comment: should i do any change in the code or the plugin itself is sufficient ?

Comment: you need to make a file for check user that completed 2 days of signup. Plugin will only run the cron file what time you describe.

Comment: plugin will do the work you dont need to do after that

Comment: and I am having some issues with the smtp mail code ? can you help mw with it ? i have written the code to send mail through smtp but its not sneding any mail.